# What is the sequence that maximizes this distance?

Tags: discrete-geometry, plane-geometry

I have posted this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221764/what-is-the-sequence-that-maximizes-this-distance) without answer. Maybe I can get some light here.

Suppose we are given $n$ segments $l_1,...,l_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $|l_i|=i,\ \forall\ i=1,...,n$, where $|l_i|$ is the length of $l_i$. Let $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{n-1}$ be $n-1$ angles such that $\alpha_i>0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\alpha_i\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Consider the following operation: (All angles are assumed to be "clockwise").

1) Place $l_{1}$ anywhere in $\mathbb{R}^2$,

2) Place $l_{2}$ at either of the end points of $l_{1}$, making an angle of $\alpha_{1}$,

3) Place $l_{3}$ at the end point of $l_{2}$ not occupied by $l_{1}$, making an angle of $\alpha_{2}$,

...

n-1) Place $l_{n-1}$ at the end point of $l_{n-2}$ not occupied by $l_{n-3}$, making an angle of $\alpha_{n-2}$,

n) Place $l_{n}$ at the end point of $l_{n-1}$ not occupied by $l_{n-2}$, making an angle of $\alpha_{n-1}$.

Now consider arbitrary permutations both of the angles $\alpha_i$ and of the lengths $l_i$. Which ordering of the angles and lengths maximizes the distance between the two endpoints of the chain of segments?

Answer (score 1):

> "Place $l_{2}$ at either of the end points of $l_{1}$, making an angle of $\alpha_{1}$"...

Making an angle $\alpha_{1}$ *with respect to which line, measured in which direction*?  Here is a possible example with $\alpha_i=\pi/8$, but until you remove the ambiguity in your stipulation, it is unclear
if this accord with your intention:

 
[image: Lengths and Angles]

The OP has now made clear that the above fails his definition.
So, if $\alpha_i$ is a constant, the distance is entirely determined.
For $\alpha_i=\pi/8$, here is the determined shape and so end-to-end distance:

          
[image: Lengths and Angles: 2nd version]

Comment: making an angle $\alpha_1$ with respect to $l_1$. All angles are assumed to be "clockwise".

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: So the above illustration fails your criteria, because the $\pi/8$ angles are not each measured clockwise? Between $l_2$ and $l_1$, the angle is clockwise. But between $l_3$ and $l_2$, it is counterclockwise. Am I correct that my drawing fails your criteria? 

Comment: I think the problem is more tractable and still interesting if the alpha_i are supplementary (or complementary? Anyway, the angles exterior to a convex polygon which add up to 2pi.) angles.  Gerhard "Geometry Was So Long Ago" Paseman, 2012.12.27

Comment: In fact, with all the alphas equal and using my intepretation, it seems clear a length increasing ordering achieves the longest endpoints.  From this I think one can also show that a monotonic angle measure ordering is required for optimality when the exterior angles alpha are different.  Gerhard "Thinking Outside All The Boxes" Paseman, 2012.12.27

Comment: @Gerhard: I like your problem (which is different from the OP's)!